# VBA Error method of '_default' if object 'range' failed when inserting formula into cell

Tags: vba, insert, formula

I am trying to use VBA to put a formula into a cell. This is the formula.

```
   Range(Cells(2, 15)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7clrow,Classes!R[]C[-13]))"
```

The error is inside the quotes on the right.  I've tried taking off range, using A1 notation, and everything else I can think of.  I have several extremely similar lines before and after that all work fine, so I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.  Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** Here is the line several people have suggested:

```
 Cells(2, 15).FormulaR1C1 = " =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'!$G$2:$G$" & lrow & ",Classes!B2))"
```

or

```
  Cells(2, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7C" & lrow & ",Classes!R[]C[-13]))"
```

Which is the same as far as I can tell.

While Mat was helping me I accidentally added a space in front of the = to create the line:

```
 Cells(2, 15).FormulaR1C1 = " =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7C" & lrow & ",Classes!R[]C[-13]))"
```

**and that line goes in just fine?**  When I move to XL and take the space out, the formula works as intended.  Does this help narrow down what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 2:** Here is what I was doing wrong - I had redefined a variable before that line that referenced another sheet.  When I did that the program apparently kept referencing that sheet, and gave me my issues.  When I changed and added the sheet before the cells (sheets(blah).cellc(blah) then it worked.  Thanks to everyone (especially Mat) who helped out.

Comment: Why pass a single cell to `Range`? Just use `Cells(2, 15).FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: Does `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7clrow,Classes!R[]C[-13]))` work as a formula?

Comment: I would guess something like `"=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7c" & lrow & ",Classes!R[]C[-13]))"` if `lrow` is a variable

Comment: Comintern - the main reason is because I'm only a month into learning.  I was trying to post this cell into several others, but simplified this line because it is giving me an issue and I thought the multiple cell part might be the issue.

Comment: Tim - Thanks for the effort, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Pretty sure R7C2 is B7, not G2.

Comment: Woah Rdster - you are right.  I'll double check which one I really meant.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7clrow,Classes!R[]C[-13]))` work as a formula?*

If it doesn't work (and no, it doesn't), then Excel itself can't assign the broken formula to the cell you're typing it in - for the exact same reason, VBA won't be able to do it either.

So you mean `lrow` to be evaluated by VBA before it's inserted into the formula, right? For this to happen, VBA needs to be able to see that `lrow` variable. Being in a string literal, it doesn't, and it can't guess at your intentions either: as far as VBA is concerned, this is what's happening:

```
SomeObject.SomeProperty = "some string literal"
```

That's all.

You need to concatenate the variable's *value* into the string literal, the way you concatenate strings in VBA:

```
SomeObject.SomeProperty = "some " & someVariable & " string literal"
```

In other words make the right-hand side of the assignment a string-valued *expression*, not just a *literal*:

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7c" & lrow & ",Classes!R[]C[-13]))"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but that still didn't fix it.  when I hover over my parts, lrow = 3173, and until I changed the right side equation the left reference was reading the correct value of the cell (118 before I paste).

Comment: @uttuck as I implied with my opening comment, the first step is to figure out a formula that works. Do that in Excel, not in VBA. Once you have a working formula, make it a string literal in VBA, and parameterize it by concatenating your variable(s). As for the hover values, I don't know what you're referring to, I'm not looking at your screen. Protip: use the *locals* window instead of hovering.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a shot.  I wasn't getting it before then.  Thanks

Comment: Note that your VBA code implicitly works off the `ActiveSheet`. Make sure the correct sheet is active when the code runs, or properly qualify the `Cells` (and/or `Range`) call.

Comment: Here is the equation that works:    "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'!$G$2:$G$3173,Classes!B2))" and here is how I'm trying to write that:     "Cells(2, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:R7C" & lrow & ",Classes!R[]C[-13]))" The error seems to be how I'm handling the range from 'All Failing Classes', because if I change that to a single cell, it works.

Comment: Sorry when I  hit enter to start a new line to make the code a line of code it submits the comment and I can't edit yet.

Comment: I've never *needed* to use R1C1 notation in 15 years of VBA coding. Not sure why you can't do `"=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'!$G$2:$G$" & lrow & ",Classes!B2))"`.

Comment: Interesting.  column[-13] works if I change the first range to a single cell.  Why wouldn't that work?  I'm simply referencing the 13th column to the left in the same row, correct?

Comment: I tried that, but, here is something else: I accidentally added a space before the = and ran the line.  It formatted the cell in XL as text and displayed what I wanted displayed.  When I removed the line in XL it became a formula again and showed the correct number.  I can't figure out why that would work, but just entering the formula wouldn't?  So without the space, error, with the space, no error.

Comment: Well then remove the space and call it a day

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cells(2, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('All Failing Classes'R7C2:r7c" & lrow & ",Classes!R[]C[-13]))"
```

I'm guessing that lrow is a variable...

Comment: It is.  I've tried that (and I should have posted that version, as I knew it was more correct, but I just posted my last and most frustrated try).  Thank you for the attempt, but it still didn't work.  I've clarified on Mat's comment.